# Inserting data to impala table using Ibis python

Tags: python, pandas, impala, ibis

I'm trying to insert df into a ibis created impala table with partition. I am running this on remote kernel using spyder 3.2.4 on windows 10 machine and python 3.6.2 on edge node machine running CentOS.

I get following error:

```
Writing DataFrame to temporary file
Writing CSV to: /tmp/ibis/pandas_0032f9dd1916426da62c8b4d8f4dfb92/0.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2910, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "", line 1, in 
insert = target_table.insert(df3)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/impala/client.py", line 1674, in insert
writer, expr = write_temp_dataframe(self._client, obj)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/impala/pandas_interop.py", line 225, in write_temp_dataframe
return writer, writer.delimited_table(path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/impala/pandas_interop.py", line 188, in delimited_table
schema = self.get_schema()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/impala/pandas_interop.py", line 184, in get_schema
return pandas_to_ibis_schema(self.df)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/impala/pandas_interop.py", line 219, in pandas_to_ibis_schema
return schema(pairs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/api.py", line 105, in schema
return Schema.from_tuples(pairs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/datatypes.py", line 109, in from_tuples
return Schema(names, types)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/datatypes.py", line 55, in init
self.types = [validate_type(typ) for typ in types]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/datatypes.py", line 55, in 
self.types = [validate_type(typ) for typ in types]

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/datatypes.py", line 1040, in validate_type
return TypeParser(t).parse()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/datatypes.py", line 901, in parse
t = self.type()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ibis/expr/datatypes.py", line 1033, in type
raise SyntaxError('Type cannot be parsed: {}'.format(self.text))

File "", line unknown
SyntaxError: Type cannot be parsed: integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Error was coming due to structure and security of the hadoop system. Ibis package tries to create temp_db & temp_hdfs_location in __ibis_tmp & /tmp/ibis/ respectively. Since in our system default locations are not open to any user other than root/system admin... insert command was erroring out when getting data from /tmp/ibis/ to actual db (still not clear but may be via __ibis_tmp dbase). Once we edited the config_init.py file for ibis package to a allowed temp location/db. It worked like a charm.

Comment: alternatively, use following:ibis.config_init.impala_temp_hdfs_path_doc = <path>

Answer (score 0):

instead of editing the config_init.py mentioned

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47543691/5485370

It is easier to assign the temp db and path using the ibis.options:

```
ibis.options.impala.temp_db = 'your_temp_db'
ibis.options.impala.temp_hdfs_path = 'your_temp_hdfs_path'
```